# How to get the react debugger to work with expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, expo

I was having trouble debugging my Expo app that uses Google authentication so I started to run it natively. When I run the app with npx `expo run:ios`, the authentication works properly, but the default debugger doesn't show react components and values, which makes it difficult to debug any issues.

I've tried to use the third-party software "React Native Debugger" to improve my debugging experience, but I'm having trouble connecting it to my app. Specifically, I'm not sure how to use the debugger with the simulator that runs when I use the npx expo run:ios command.

Is there a way to get the debugger to show react components or to use the React Native Debugger with the simulator that runs with `npx expo run:ios`? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/). You can take a look at the [expo docs for it](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-flipper/). It may be pain to use and have [compatibility issues](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-flipper/#limitations) but you can use it to view the component tree